# How do I use tar using an absolute path from user input to backup a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I have a script that gets the input from the user as an absolute path (using the fselect dialog box).

```
backupdir=$(user_select "choose a directory backup destination");
```

I used

```
tar cvzf backup.tar.gz $backupdir
```

however this includes the absolute directory path (*1) so instead I attempted (out-with the script):

```
tar czvf backup.tar.gz -C $PATH directory-to-backup
```

Therefore, in my script I can use:

```
pathtodir = dirname $backupdir
```

to get the $PATH of the backup directory but I need the name of the directory I wish to backup i.e:

```
dirname = ..
tar czvf backup.tar.gz -C $PATH $dirname
```

**How do I get the name of $dirname?**

<sub>1 -  "Removing leading `/' from member name"</sub>

Comment: GNU tar? If so, check out `--strip-components=NUMBER` ...

Comment: so that would be on extraction?

Comment: That's during packing. `-C` can be used in both cases, AFAIK. Even if it didn't, you could do `(cd $dirname && tar ...)` inside a subshell (restoring the old cwd after the subshell exits). Oh, and I think the order of the arguments might play a role. Try putting the `-C` as first parameter, or definitely before the `f` and its argument.

Comment: Could compare the values of the variables? i.e. pathtodir='path/to/dir' backupdir='path/to/dir/backupdir' and somehow get the difference so that I'm left with 'backupdir'?

Comment: Sure: string substitution such as `${backupdir//$pathtodir/}` (in Bash only, though) ... side-note: given where we are going with this, I think you should rephrase your question a bit. Wasn't really clear to me that this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to be honest I had some difficulty to figure out the question at first. I think we sorted that in the comments.

So you have `$backupdir` which contains the absolute path to the backup directory, plus `$pathtodir` which is a parent directory of the backup directory.

You can now use string substitution in Bash as follows:

```
# Replace $pathtodir with empty string inside $backupdir
relativepath=${backupdir//$pathtodir/}
# Now remove the leading slash, if any
relativepath=${relativepath#/}
```

If I misunderstood something still, let me know and I'll adjust the answer accordingly.